# 'int' object has no attribute 'update' - dictionary within dictionary - python2.7

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I did my best with looking for similar questions on this site and digging through the manual. Unfortunatelly after few hours and wee headache I gave up ... it is a massively rookie question, but would appreciate any help!!!

I've got a list:

```
PriceList = [['WGH', 'A1', 100], ['WGH', 'A2', 125], ['WGH', 'A3', 150],
             ['RIE', 'A1', 75], ['RIE', 'A2', 125]]
```

I'm trying to convert it to the Dictionary that will look like this:

```
Dict1 = {'WGH': {'A1': 100, 'A2': 125, 'A3': 150}, 'RIE': {'A1': 75, 'A2': 125}}
```

So far I tried following:

```
PriceList = [['WGH', 'A1', 100], ['WGH', 'A2', 125], ['WGH', 'A3', 150],
             ['RIE', 'A1', 75], ['RIE', 'A2', 125]]

Dict1 = {c[0]:0 for c in PriceList}
Dict2 = {c[0]:0 for c in PriceList}

for line in PriceList:
    addition = {line[0]:{line[1]:line[2]}}
    addition2 = {line[1]:line[2]}

    print addition
    print addition2

    Dict1.update(addition)
    #Dict2[line[0]].update(addition2)
```

print statements were just for me to make sure data is being converted into dictionaries

Line 'Dict1.update(addition)' is the closest I manage to get, but it only gives me last record for each key.

hashed line of the code is the one I'm strugling with, if try to run it I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'update'
```

I think it is something to do with me trying to use Dict[line[0]], but now sure how to work around it.

Please let me know if you would need more info and thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have built dictionaries containing integers:

```
Dict1 = {c[0]:0 for c in PriceList}
```

If they should contain dictionaries instead, then do create them:

```
Dict1 = {c[0]: {} for c in PriceList}
```

Now you can update these dictionaries in your loop:

```
for line in PriceList:
    Dict1[line[0]][line[1]] = line[2]
```

Demo:

```
>>> PriceList = [['WGH', 'A1', 100], ['WGH', 'A2', 125], ['WGH', 'A3', 150],
...              ['RIE', 'A1', 75], ['RIE', 'A2', 125]]
>>> Dict1 = {c[0]: {} for c in PriceList}
>>> for line in PriceList:
...     Dict1[line[0]][line[1]] = line[2]
... 
>>> Dict1
{'RIE': {'A1': 75, 'A2': 125}, 'WGH': {'A1': 100, 'A3': 150, 'A2': 125}}
```

Comment: Oh my god, so simple!!! works like a charm :) I will accept this answer as soon as time limit expires. Thank you very much Martijn!!!